# Couldn't connect to AWS MQTT Client in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, connection, mqtt

I'm trying to connect to AWS MQTT Broker.
I've tried several ways to do it, but i cannot find a way to do it.
The app, while debugging, seems that find and accept certificates, but still not connect to the broker.
"Broker doesn't respond to {endpoint}:{port}" Is the result of every try.
This code is part of a Windows Forms project, in .NET Framework 4.7.2.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;   //for Regex Class
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MQTTnet;          //version 3.0.16
using MQTTnet.Client;
using MQTTnet.Client.Connecting;
using MQTTnet.Client.Disconnecting;
using MQTTnet.Client.Options;
using MQTTnet.Client.Subscribing;
using MQTTnet.Extensions.ManagedClient;
using MQTTnet.Formatter;
using MQTTnet.Server;

namespace MQTTprj
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Regex ipRegex = new Regex(@"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$");
        public Regex hostnameRegex = new Regex(@"^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*[a-zA-Z0-9])$");
        //log section string 
        private StringBuilder logMessages = new StringBuilder();
        private IMqttClient _mqttClient;
        

        //check if the string is such as "example.com"
        bool check_hostname(string endpoint)
        {
            return hostnameRegex.IsMatch(endpoint);
        }
        //check if the string is such as "192.168.0.1"
        bool check_ip(string endpoint)
        {
            return ipRegex.IsMatch(endpoint);
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void btn_connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_mqttClient != null && _mqttClient.IsConnected)
                {
                    AddLog($"Client already connected to {this.endpoint.Text}:{int.Parse(this.port.Text)}");

                }
                else
                {
                    
                    //clear log
                    logMessages.Clear();
                    txt_log.Text = "";
                    //check if the port is a number and the address are valid
                    if (int.TryParse(port.Text, out int port_num) && (check_hostname(endpoint.Text) || check_ip(endpoint.Text)))
                    {
                        if (port_num < 1 || port_num > 65535)
                        {
                            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Input Error: port must be inside (1 - 65535) range");
                        }
                        var factory = new MqttFactory();
                        _mqttClient = factory.CreateMqttClient();

                        var endpoint = this.endpoint.Text;
                        var port = int.Parse(this.port.Text);
                        var clientCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("AmazonRootCA1.pem");
                        var caCert = new X509Certificate2("certificate.pem.crt", "private.pem.key");

                          IMqttClientOptions options = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                                .WithTcpServer(endpoint, port)
                                .WithCredentials("test", "testcl")
                                .WithProtocolVersion(MqttProtocolVersion.V311)
                                .WithTls(new MqttClientOptionsBuilderTlsParameters
                                {
                                    UseTls = true,
                                    SslProtocol = SslProtocols.Tls12,
                                    AllowUntrustedCertificates = false,
                                    Certificates = new List<X509Certificate>()
                                      {
                                          clientCert,
                                          caCert
                                      }
                                })
                                // .WithClientId(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                                .WithClientId("Merlin")
                                .Build();
                      
                        if (!_mqttClient.IsConnected)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                _mqttClient.ConnectAsync(options).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                                if (_mqttClient.IsConnected)
                                {
                                    AddLog($"Client successfully connected to {endpoint}:{port}");
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                AddLog($"Broker doesn't respond to {endpoint}:{port} ");
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            AddLog($"Client already connected to {endpoint}:{port}");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new FormatException("Input Error: the endpoint or port are not valid, check if they are correct and retry.");
                    }
                }


            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                logMessages.Append(ex.Message + "\r\n");
                txt_log.Text = logMessages.ToString();

            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
            {
                logMessages.Append(ex.Message + "\r\n");
                txt_log.Text = logMessages.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logMessages.Append(ex.Message + "\r\n");
                txt_log.Text = logMessages.ToString();
            }


        }

        private void btn_disconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            logMessages.Clear();
            txt_log.Text = "";
            if (_mqttClient.IsConnected)
            {
                _mqttClient?.DisconnectAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                if (!_mqttClient.IsConnected)
                {
                    AddLog("Disconnected");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                AddLog("No Client was started");
            }


        }

        private void btn_publish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_mqttClient.IsConnected)
            {
                var topic = this.topic.Text;
                var message = this.message.Text;

                var mqttMessage = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
                    .WithTopic(topic)
                    .WithPayload(message)
                    .WithExactlyOnceQoS()
                    .WithRetainFlag()
                    .Build();

                _mqttClient.PublishAsync(mqttMessage).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                AddLog($"Published message to topic '{topic}': {message}");
            }
            else
            {
                AddLog("Before connect a client to a broker");
            }
        }
        private void AddLog(string message)
        {
            this.txt_log.AppendText($"[{DateTime.Now}] {message}{Environment.NewLine}");
        }
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            _mqttClient?.DisconnectAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }


        private void btn_subscribe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                if (_mqttClient.IsConnected && _mqttClient != null)
                {
                    //setting up the handler
                    _mqttClient.UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler(session =>
                    {
                        var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(session.ApplicationMessage.Payload);
                        BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            txt_log.AppendText("Received JSON data: " + json + Environment.NewLine);
                        }));

                    });
                    //set up topic filter
                    var topic = this.topic.Text;
                    var topicfilter = new MqttTopicFilterBuilder().WithTopic(topic).Build();
                    //verifing the subscribe was successful
                    MQTTnet.Client.Subscribing.MqttClientSubscribeResult sub_res = _mqttClient.SubscribeAsync(topicfilter).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    if (sub_res.Items[0].ResultCode == MqttClientSubscribeResultCode.GrantedQoS1 || sub_res.Items[0].ResultCode == MqttClientSubscribeResultCode.GrantedQoS2 || sub_res.Items[0].ResultCode == MqttClientSubscribeResultCode.GrantedQoS0)
                    {

                        AddLog("Successfully subscribed to topic. " + topic);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddLog("Failed to subscribe to topic. " + topic);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    //throw new NullReferenceException("Before specify a client to a broker");
                    AddLog("Before connect a client to a broker");
                }
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                AddLog("Before connect a client to a broker");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[layout of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pALvs.png)
Without using ".WithTls(parameters)", i can connect in a local broker.

Comment: The TLS parameters are giving an issue.  TLS you can use either version 1.2 or 1.3.  The certificate contains the encryption mode and some modes are are only supported in 1.2 or 1.3 (see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security?force_isolation=true).  You have a list of required certificates and one of these certificates has to be loaded in both client and server.  TLS the server sends a certificate block with names of allowed certificates.  The client look up the names in the stores to find matching certificate.

Comment: Your code has a list of specific certificates to work which may not match the server list.

Comment: using MQTT.fx, with these certificates, it works.
Is there a way to know if my certificates are expired?

Comment: PEM files have text sections with expiration date that you can read with any text editor.

Comment: how can i use TLS 1.3? There isn't in my options list.

Comment: certification files are still valid

Comment: If i change it to default, the error message changes into: "A call SSPI failed, see inner exception."

Comment: Change to : SslProtocol = SslProtocols.Tls12 |  SslProtocols.Tls13;

Comment: Either if i don't have it in my list of sslprotocols?

Comment: It is a word with each bit indicating a different protocol.  If you do not have TLS13 than you are using an old Framework before 4.7.2 (or older OS).  With 4.7.2 TLS is performed by OS unless there is a setting in the csproj file to use Net which is not recommended. Your MQTT may be on a Win 2008 server that doesn't support TLS 1.3.

Comment: My project version is in .net Framework 4.7.2 and it still doesn't work.
I've updated it to Framework 4.8 and i have finally "unlocked" Tls13.
Now the issue is that, during execution, i get this error while i'm trying to connect to the broker: MQTTnet.Exceptions.MqttCommunicationTimedOutException: 'The operation has been cancelled.'

Comment: Timeout usually means TLS is still not working.  The certificate may not be installed on both client and server.  TLS is performed before the HTTP Request is sent.  c# cannot detect when TLS fails because it is performed by operating system automatically.  So timeout exception is used to indicate a response was never returned.  So it can mean TLS failed, you attempted to connect to wrong server, the server wasn't listening, or the server didn't send back a response.